# chart.js dynamically adjust gap between vertical bars

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, chart.js

I am working on a webpage that presents dashboard on th basis of invoice processing project.

using below code i am populating bar chart.

```
function loadVolumeChart()
{
  var pieChartContent = document.getElementById('chartAreaWrapper');
  pieChartContent.innerHTML = '';
  $('#chartAreaWrapper').append('<canvas id="line-chart" height="300" width="1500px"><canvas>');   
  //getData For Volume Analysis Chary    
  var url_string = document.referrer;;
  var url = new URL(url_string);
  var name = url.searchParams.get("name");
  var user=url.searchParams.get("user");
  var team=url.searchParams.get("team");
  var date=url.searchParams.get("date");
  var dates = [];
  var count = [];

  var from = date.split("-")[0];
  var to = date.split("-")[1];
  var re=$.ajax({
    url: 'getTotalCounts.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        from:from,
        to:to,
        team:team,
        totalVolume: '00'
    },
    async:false,
    success: function(data) {
      var result =data;
      var json = JSON.parse(result);
      dates=json[0].data;//json[0].data;
      count=json[1].data;
      //alert(dates);
    }
    }).done(function(data){
      // openPage(data);
    }).fail(function(data){
      alert(data.responseText);
    });
    //volume chart
   new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'bar', //line
  data: {
  labels:dates,
  datasets: [{ 
  data:count,
    label: "Total Inward",
    backgroundColor: "#0E6655", //borderColor
    fill: true
  },
]
  },

  options: {

  responsive:false,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  legend: {
        display: false
     },
     tooltips: {
        enabled: true
     },
     scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            display:false
        },
        barThickness: 15,

    }],
    yAxes: [{
      barPercentage: 1.0,
categoryPercentage: 1.0,
        gridLines: {
            display:false
        },
        ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max:10,
            stepSize: 1
            }   
    }]
},
  }
});
//end of volume chart
     }
```

But the problem is when data is low, means if the x axis data contains only 2 dates, then the gap between two bars is too large, like the image below,
[image]

but if i add more dates then the gap reduces.i want to set gap between two bars even if their are only two bars. the gap between both should not increase if the dates (bars) according to the size of x axis data. if the data is large then it should only scroll. thats why i have added scroll bar.

the div of chart is as:

```
 <div class="parentDiv" >
     <div class="chartAreaWrapper" id="chartAreaWrapper" style="height:80%;width:70%;margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;float: left;">
     <canvas id="line-chart" height="300" width="1500px"></canvas>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the option `xAxis.barThickness` defines that the width of individual bars has to be of 15 pixels. Simply remove this option.

> You should also consider to use the latest stable version of Chart.js (currently v2.9.3) where the option `xAxis.barThickness` is deprecated. The options `barThickness`, `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage` are now part of the [dataset configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration).

Comment: I tries, and removed barThickness but it increases the thikness of bars, as i have only 4-5 bars in my graph then they should be visible in chart area, but the bars are getting expanded in scrollpane

Comment: That's how Chart.js works, it evenly spreads the bars over the available space on the `xAxis`. Since you defined the canvas width to be 1500px, that's what you get.